# Enable to disable krmapihosting.googleapis.com or container.googleapis.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We have a kubernetes cluster that keep getting up even if we delete it via the GCP interface.
We would like to totally disable the Kubenertes API to avoid this behavior but, when trying to disable via the interface it shows an Unknown error.

When using the CLI, we have an error even using `gcloud services disable krmapihosting.googleapis.com --force`

[image]

We have nothing that seems running on compute engine nor kubernetes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cli commands try using cloud console by following the steps:

To disable an API for a project:

1. Go to the console [API Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/apis/dashboard) page.
2. Select the Cloud project where you want to disable an API.
3. Click the API you want to disable. If you need help finding the API, use
   the Search for APIs & Services box near the top of the page. A page
   describing the API appears.(for your issue search for
   krmapihosting.googleapis.com or container.googleapis.com)
4. Click stop Disable API.

For more information follow [Disabling services](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable#disabling).